# binding kendo dropdown using ngModel to an interpolated value results in error

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to bind kendo-dropdown in my dynamic table and getting error

```
    Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{f.value.CogencyClassId}}] in ng:///ManagerStrategyModule/FundClassesComponent.html@134:63 ("!--  {{f.value.CogencyClassId}} -->
                    <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]= "{{f.value.CogencyClassId}}"
```

I have tried couple of options like but none of them seem to work

```
 [(ngModel)]= "{{f.value.CogencyClassId}}"
 [(ngModel)]=  {{f.value.CogencyClassId}}
 [(ngModel)]= '{{f.value.CogencyClassId}}'
```

Here is my HTML

```
 <table class="fundClassesTable" >

        <tr>
           <th class="tableItem bold">Cogency Class?</th>
        </tr>


<ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel" >
            <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">

               <td class="tableItem">      <!--  {{f.value.CogencyClassId}} -->
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]= "{{f.value.CogencyClassId}}" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                        [data]= "FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.CogencyClasses" [filterable]="false"  textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"
                        ></kendo-dropdownlist>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

Json

```
{"FundDetailsViewModel":[{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":0,"FundId":0,"ShareClass":"Assign Cogency Fund First","LocalCurrency":null,"Name":"Assign Cogency Fund First "}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":250033,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11166,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":5508},{"Id":100541,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11167,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":5508}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":1},{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":1}]},{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":1121,"FundId":652,"ShareClass":"Class B","LocalCurrency":"USD","Name":"Class B USD"}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":250028,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":23732600,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":1121,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250032,"Description":"Class D","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13714,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250031,"Description":"Class C","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13715,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250030,"Description":"Class B1","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13716,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250029,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":119307314,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13717,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B1","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class C","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class D","ClassType":3}]}],"VehicleTypes":[{"Spf":false,"Name":"Secondaries","SortOrder":null,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Co-Investment (non-SPF)","SortOrder":1,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":false,"Name":"FX Trade","SortOrder":2,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed ETF","SortOrder":3,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed Security","SortOrder":4,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Mutual Fund","SortOrder":5,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Offshore Fund","SortOrder":6,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":7,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US Non - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":8,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"EnTrustPermal Product","SortOrder":9,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Standard","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – 40 Act","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – UCITS","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Blocker","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Co-Investment","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Special Sit","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Private Equity","SortOrder":11,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Side-Pocket","SortOrder":12,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Special Situation (non-SPF)","SortOrder":13,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Third Party Fund of Funds","SortOrder":14,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"UCITS","SortOrder":15,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Other","SortOrder":50,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false}],"ClosureStatuses":[{"Id":110,"Name":"Hard Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":111,"Name":"Open","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":112,"Name":"Soft Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":1,"Name":"Open - to all","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Open - to Permal only","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Closed - hard","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":104,"Name":"Closed - with wait list","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":4},{"Id":100,"Name":"Closed - but will reopen","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":21,"Name":"Closed - but replacing redemptions","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":6},{"Id":101,"Name":"Redemptions Gated","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":7},{"Id":102,"Name":"Redemptions Suspended","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":8},{"Id":103,"Name":"In Liquidation","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":9}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  for

- Two way binding

`[(ngModel)]="f.value.CogencyClassId"`

- One way binding

`[ngModel]="f.value.CogencyClassId"`

---

### In your code :

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]= "f.value.CogencyClassId" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                        [data]= "FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.CogencyClasses" [filterable]="false"  textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"
                        ></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and the error has gone but it isnt populating the dropdown. I have updated the post with the json

Comment: May be you need set Id with dynamic value